# React MUI Autocomplete "options.filter" is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I wish to create a autocomplete search bar with my own custom call to the backend, which searches through a list of tickers.

```js
<Autocomplete
                multiple
                id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
                options={watchlistSearchTickers}
                disableCloseOnSelect
                getOptionLabel={(option: any) => (option!) ? option.Symbol : null}
                renderOption={(props, option, { selected }) => (
                    <li {...props}>
                        {option.Symbol}
                    </li>
                )}
                style={{ padding: 0 }}
                onChange={(event, query: any) => handleWatchlistSearch(query)}
                filterOptions={(x) => x}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                    <div ref={params.InputProps.ref}>
                        <input type="text" {...params.inputProps} />
                    </div>
                )}
            />
```

The initial render here seems fine, but on click the text input box, an error `"options.filter" is not a function` occurs. Here is the function that calls the backend through a post request:

```js
const [watchlistSearchTickers, setWatchlistSearchTickers] = useState<Array<watchlistSearchInterface>>([])

function handleWatchlistSearch(query: string) {
        axiosInstance.post("/portfolio/watchlist/search/", {
            query: query
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
            setWatchlistSearchTickers(res.data)
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        handleWatchlistSearch("")
    }, []) // Initialize with empty list of tickers
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this bug actually happens when you pass `null` or `undefined` values into the `options` prop of the Autocomplete component. This is likely happening because you're clicking in the Autocomplete "too fast", so before it can get the results from your API call, it passes a value that the component tries to `.filter()` it, causing the error.

I was also having this issue, and I managed to figure a workaround that works (it's not perfect but it stops your code from crashing).

```
<Autocomplete
            multiple
            id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
            options={!watchlistSearchTickers ? [{label:"Loading...", id:0}] : watchlistSearchTickers }
(...)
```

With this ternary, what we do is that while your API is working on your request, it puts a placeholder "Loading..." option so it won't crash your code (Similar-ish to the [Load on open prop](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#load-on-open), but I never figured how to make that work).

For me the solution above works well, but the fanciest and best choice would be the [Load](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#load-on-open) prop that is something from MUI.

Hope I could help!

Edit: Actually, if you can initialize your options to an empty array [], you can set the loading prop as true, which will display loading while your content loads!